# Tkinter grid_columnconfigure of canvas and frame not sync together

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm constructing a script below, the aim is to make a scrollbar area with title freeze on top. I'm using grid because I feel most comfortable with it and also it allow me to adjust area easier.

```
from tkinter import *

class maingui(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.rowconfigure(0,minsize = 50,weight = 1)
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.master, width=1200, height=100, borderwidth = 1, relief='solid')
        button1 = Button(self.frame1, text = 'Run cmd', command = self.create_canvas)
        button1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor = 'n')
        self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.master, borderwidth = 1, width=1200, height=1100, relief='solid')
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')
        self.frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)        
    def create_canvas(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame2, width=1200, height=900, borderwidth = 1, relief='solid')
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame2, orient = 'vertical',command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')
        self.canvas_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')
        self.canvas_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight = 1, uniform = 'col')

        Label(self.frame2, text = 'Data 1').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        Label(self.frame2, text = 'Data 2').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Label(self.frame2, text = 'Data 3').grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        for x in range(0,501):

            Label(self.canvas_frame, text = 'Row %d - Column 1'%(x)).grid(row = x, column = 0)
            Label(self.canvas_frame, text = 'Row %d - Column 2'%(x)).grid(row = x, column = 1)
            Label(self.canvas_frame, text = 'Row %d - Column 3'%(x)).grid(row = x, column = 2)            


        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.canvas.create_window(0,0, window = self.canvas_frame, anchor = 'nw')
        self.canvas.bind(
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.scroll.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 43, column = 4, sticky = 'ns')
root = Tk()
a = maingui(root)
root.geometry('1200x1200')
root.mainloop()
```

However, the GUI like the picture below has shown that the size of column between frame and canvas are not the same, in fact grid_columnconfigure not work on canvas. Link to image: [result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMDXI.png)

Comment: You are correct that they are not in sync. The grid in each containing widget is designed to be independent.

Comment: @BryanOakley so is there any solution to correct this?